# POST / GET Request Param Validation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot. I want to validated the POST request params. So I have gine through @Validated annotation but this require creating a different class for Every API. How should I write my code?

As for example, this is my api

```
@RequestMapping("/tags/{tagId}/{tagParentId}")

public Response<Demo> a(@PathVariable int tagId, @PathVariable int tagParentId){ 
   ... code
}


@RequestMapping("/data/{courseId}/{instId}")
public Response<Demo> b(@PathVariable int courseId, @PathVariable int instId){ 
   ... code
}
```

How should I change my code to add params validation for there API's such that I do not need to create two different validation class? Just one class and then I can add different functions for different API's.

Answer (score 1):

@Validated should be used, to check that a parameter is syntactical correct.

As you are using int values, this is already done by spring.
If tagId is not a valid int, the client will already receive a Http error code.

The validation, whether there is a tag with the given tagId is implicitly done in your code, you do not need an additional validator for that.

If you read tags for example from the database, and you cannot find a tag for the tagId, you should

```
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

from your controller method.

You may need to change the return type of your controller method to a common superclass or just to Object, to allow returning the ResponseEntity.

Its also possible to throw exceptions in the controller methods and to configure spring to return a regarding HttpStatus.
See [exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)